# Refactor double foreach and if statment into java 8 solution

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

Well like you can notice I try to get users on a specific project (and my code works)

```
List<User> allUsers = userRepository.findAll();
List<UserDto> usersInSpecificProject = new ArrayList<>();

for(User user: allUsers){
    Set<Project> allProjects = user.getProjects();
    for(Project project: allProjects){
    if(project.getId().equals(projectId)){
            usersInSpecificProject.add(user);
        }
    }
}
```

If it would've been single for + if I could easily do something like:

```
allUsers.stream()
    .filter(u -> u.someCondition)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But what if I need to loop in a loop?

Comment: You can add a method in User called hasProject(ProjectId projectId), this can be your condition. Why do you want 2 for loops?

Comment: Well, I want to get all users from the specific project. That's why I need to loop through all Users. Check their Projects. and then check if their projects have id with the specific ID. Is there an easier way to achive that?

Comment: You seem to be using a database - it would be more efficient and simpler to write the ad hoc query.

Comment: You have a Set of Projects in User. You can use the for loop in there to check if the User has the project -> create method in User **hasProject** which can be called in the filter. But iso using for loop you can also change Set<Project> to HashMap<ProjectId,Project> . Then inside your method you can return map.contains(projectId).

Comment: If you're trying to optimize this, you shouldn't use `userRepository.findAll()` there to begin with. Use actual database operation, like `findByProject` or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this:

```
List<User> usersInSpecificProject =
  allUsers.stream()
        .filter(u -> u.getProjects().stream()
                                    .map(Project::getId)
                                    .anyMatch(pid -> pid.equals(projectId)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Your original version should be improved by `break` after condition `if(project.getId().equals(projectId))` is satisfied.

That's why the `filter` using `anyMatch()` to break on first match.

For more elegant version, you could factor our the filter:

```
Predicate<User> hasProject = u -> u.getProjects().stream()
                                   .map(Project::getId)
                                   .anyMatch(pid -> pid.equals(projectId));
List<User> result = allUsers.stream().filter(hasProject).collect(toList());
```

Comment: Or `anyMatch(projectId::equals)`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like so,

```
List<User> users = allUsers.stream()
        .filter(u -> u.getProjects().stream().anyMatch(p -> p.getId().equals(projectId)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

For each user, you need to have a `filter` `predicate` to check whether the user has a project with the given `projectId` value. If so, we merely collect the satisfying `User` objects into a result container.

In case if you need to transform `User` domain objects into `UserDto` type as mentioned in your problem statement, you need to have an additional `map` function for the conversion like this.

```
List<UserDto> users = allUsers.stream()
        .filter(u -> u.getProjects().stream().anyMatch(p -> p.getId().equals(projectId)))
        .map(u -> new UserDto(u.getProjects()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

However you may have to change that according to your `UserDto` class.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Java 8's `stream()` function like this to achieve it:

```
usersInSpecificProject.addAll(allUsers.stream()
        .filter(u -> u.getProjects().stream().map(Project::getId)
        .anyMatch(projId-> projId.equals(projectId)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Here is the link to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) on how `stream()` works.

Comment: That won't work: after `flatMap`, this is a `Stream<Project>`, not `Stream<User>`.